# How to Convert Firebase Querysnapshots to an Array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to return selected teams from a collection of teams. It seems like I need to convert the snapshot to the Team object. How do I do that? Is there an easier way to convert a snapshot into an array? I am new to firebase/angular so hopefully I am missing something simple.

using angular 5.5.2

```
export class Team {
    internalTeamName: string;
    externalTeamName: string;
    creatorNumber: number;
    teamAdmins: TeamMember[];
    teamMembers: TeamMember[];
    constructor(code ommitted)
}
```

service.module

```
loadTeams(email){
const teamArray: Team[] = null;
this.firestore.collection('teams', ref => ref.where('teamAdmins', 'array-contains', email))
.get()
.forEach(function(childSnapshot) { 
teamArray.push(childSnapshot);})
.then(
   return teamArray )
.catch(
  err => console.log(err)
)
```

The error from the above code:
Argument of type 'QuerySnapshot' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Team'.
Type 'QuerySnapshot' is missing the following properties from type 'Team': internalTeamName, externalTeamName, creatorNumber, teamAdmins, teamMembers

function calling the above function:  What is the best practice when calling service functions?

```
public teamArray: Team[] = null;

ngOnInit() {
this.teamArray = this.teamCrudService.loadTeams(this.authService.email);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## How to Convert a querySnapshot into an Array on (at least) Firebase 9+

**TL;DR**: Try using `querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())`

Example usage:

```js
async function getUsers() {
  let querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'users'))
  return querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
}
```

`querySnapshot.docs` returns an array of `documentSnapshot` objects, and those have a `.data()` method that returns the real values you're looking for.

So far from what I've read, in their docs they showcase that you can use `querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {etc.})` but I haven't seen them show the method I mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

`.collection().get()` Does not return an array; it returns a QuerySnapshot, which has a *property* `.docs`, which is an array of `QueryDocumentSnapshot`, each of which has a *property* `.data`, which is the data read from the document.

Please, give a look to the public documentation
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference